# Why is Nginx truncating the gRPC streaming response?

Tags: nginx, flask, grpc, gunicorn, gevent

I've asked this question before but decided to delete that old question and reformulate it along with a [minimum reproducible example](https://github.com/SSSOC-CAN/nginx_issue). The issue is that when I deploy my gunicorn webserver on nginx, my streamed responses from my go server via gRPC get truncated. All details can be found in the repository. My nginx configuration for this site looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
    #include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_buffering off;
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    }
}
```

The code receiving and parsing the response on the front end looks like this:

```
        <script>
            (async function(){
                const response = await fetch("{{ url_for('realtimedata') }}");
                const reader = response.body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader();
                while (true) {
                    const {done, value} = await reader.read();
                    if (done) break;
                    try {
                        console.log('Received', value);
                        const rtd = JSON.parse(value);
                        console.log('Parsed', rtd);
                    } catch(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }
            })()
        </script>
```

Something to note regarding the data from the go server, one service is providing a data object with 96 fields and another service is providing data with 200 fields. Which makes the incoming stream response have variable length (in terms of bytes).

I want to use gunicorn because I may have multiple listeners at the same time. Using gunicorn solved an issue where all the responses were making it to the webserver but they were being distributed among the active clients. So each client would get a different response but not all of them.

**EDIT:**
I've tried changing the response object size on the goserver to be the same from both services but the truncating still happened. Having variable length doesn't seem to be the issue. I've also tried doing this with uWSGI instead of gunicorn and the issue persists. I even set `uwsgi_buffering off;` and the issue persists.

**UPDATE:**
I've ran the minimum reproducible example with Apache2 instead of Nginx and I'm getting the same issue. Maybe the issue is with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your python code, it seems like pushing the data from the backend to the frontend would be done better with websockets. I've rewritten your backend to use FastAPI instead of Flask and modified the nginx configuration.

`main.py`

```
import asyncio
import dependencies.rpc_pb2 as r
import dependencies.rpc_pb2_grpc as rpc
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import grpc
import json
import os

os.environ["GRPC_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES"] = 'HIGH+ECDSA'

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
server_addr = "localhost"
server_port = 3567

@app.get("/")
def read_root(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

def parseRtd(rtd):
    rtdDict = {}
    rtdDict["source"] = rtd.source
    rtdDict["is_scanning"] = rtd.is_scanning
    rtdDict["timestamp"] = int(rtd.timestamp)
    rtdDict["data"] = {}
    for key, v in rtd.data.items():
        rtdDict["data"][int(key)] = {"name": v.name, "value": v.value}
    return rtdDict

def get_rtd():
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel(f"{server_addr}:{server_port}")
    stub = rpc.RpcServiceStub(channel)
    for rtd in stub.SubscribeDataStream(r.SubscribeDataRequest()):
        yield parseRtd(rtd)

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    await websocket.send_json({"test": "this is a test"})
    it = get_rtd()
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        payload = next(it)
        await websocket.send_json(payload)
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.4.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-nYuHvSAhY5lFZ4ixSViOwsEKFvlxHMU2NHts1ILuJgOS6ptUmAGt/0i5czIgMOahKZ6JN84YFDA+mCdky7dD8A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000/ws");     
            ws.onopen = function () {
                console.log("websocket was open");
            };
            ws.onclose = () => {
                console.log("Websocket was closed!");
            }
            ws.onerror = (error) =>{
                console.error("Websocket error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            };
            ws.onmessage = (message) => {
                console.log("MSG: " + message.data );
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`webserver.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }

    location /ws {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }
}
```